# Deleting empty rows from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm unable to get the `DELETE` statement to work when trying to delete empty rows in my database display. Right now I'm getting out puts that looks like this:

```
  Column 1          Column2
 | Example 1| 
 | Example 2|
 | Example 3|
 | Example 4|
                   |Example 5|
                   |Example 6|
                   |Example 7|
                   |Example 8|
```

I would like the output to be:

```
  Column 1          Column 2
| Example 1 |     | Example 5|
| Example 2 |     | Example 6|
| Example 3 |     | Example 7|
```

I'm taking user input from a form and have 3 different fields that insert into 1 database table, but I don't require that all 3 fields be filled out before inserting. Obviously this results in empty rows if the user decides to only fill out 1 or 2 of the input fields.

I've tried using the `DELETE FROM table WHERE input =NULL"`but I either get an error or it simply doesn't work ( Depending on where I place it in the code).

```
 mysql_connect("page.ipagemysql.com", "site", "site") or    die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("site") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY storyn DESC ") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query(" DELETE FROM table WHERE input2=NULL") 
 or die(mysql_error());
```

The above example changes nothing, where as the below example gives me an error message

```
 mysql_connect("page.ipagemysql.com", "site", "site") or    die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("site") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table DELETE FROM table WHERE input2=NULL ORDER BY storyn DESC ") 
 or die(mysql_error());
```

Am I placing the `DELETE` statement in the wrong location? where am I going wrong here?

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: But it looks like you want to match Example 1 to Example 5? How ould your update know that it doesn't need to put example 6 in the same row as example 1?

Comment: If you want to fix your `delete` query have a look at Jens answer but if you want a query to _shift_ the row data (like in your output example) then you are going the wrong way.

Comment: @ForguesR I'm trying to achieve the example output, but am obviously having issues doing that. I was thinking that if I could delete the empty spacing, that it would shift column 2 up automatically. I'm assuming by your answer that this is not the case?

Comment: @Nanne I have the input fields set up to output the data into the appropriate `div`. Maybe this is the wrong way to go about it, but that aspect has at least been working lol.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to require all the fields to be filled?  This would save you a lot of trouble thereafter.

Comment: You should be aware that a database is NOT the same as a big xls table. There is no real concept of 'up' and 'down', so you cannot shift. This is a fundamental thing to understand. You have rows, and these rows have columns. you cannot remove a 'cell'. You can empty a cell, but you don't want that, as they are allready empty. Fix the way the database is filled.

Comment: @ForguesR The idea was that I could use the form to update a page on a website. You could choose which column you wanted to update as you were submitting information. Obviously if you have content for column 1, you don't need to update column2 and column3. I'm new to the backend of web development so this has been a "learn as you go" method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will all depend on how an empty value is stored to your database. If it gets stored as an empty string, which is often the case you need to use

```
delete from table where input2=''
```

Though it is better practice to check for is null or empty like int Jens' answer.

However, neither will result in the query results that you want in your example. When you run a delete, it deletes the entire row so

```
delete from table where column2 is null or column2=''
```

will result in your table looking like

```
 Column 1          Column2
                   |Example 5|
                   |Example 6|
                   |Example 7|
                   |Example 8|
```

not

```
  Column 1          Column 2
| Example 1 |     | Example 5|
| Example 2 |     | Example 6|
| Example 3 |     | Example 7|
```

Something like that will possibly  require a database design, such as extracting column1 and column2 into their own tables and determining some kind of a relationship between the two, or a far more complicated query where you need to determine the relationship between the two columns and perform some combination of updating and deleting.

Comment: well that sucks that the output that I want can't be achieved without going a much more difficult route. Your answer was very detailed and to the point. thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it was a bit difficult for me to wrap my head around. Basically you can think of each row in a table as an object. A delete will remove the entire object from the collection. Actually I find thinking about rows in tables as objects can make a lot of concepts in SQL easier. To a point at least.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
$data = mysql_query(" DELETE FROM table WHERE input2 IS NULL OR input2=''")
```

not

```
$data = mysql_query(" DELETE FROM table WHERE input2=NULL")
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you cannot use "=" to test if a value is null or not. You need to use `IS NULL` in your condition. Note that it is case-insensitive. So your query would be:

```
$data = mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE input2 IS NULL")
```

Also consider that NULL is different from an empty value. So you may optimise your query as follow:

```
$data = mysql_query(" DELETE FROM table WHERE input2 IS NULL OR input2 = ''")
```